# sorting a variant?

Tags: excel, vba

Could anyone please help me with sorting a variant

```
   var_a = activesheet.range("A3:AL" & lastrow ).value 

   var_a 1 column has some numbers
   var_a 2 column has dates 2/22/2011 like these
   var_a 3 column some other and so on
```

Now the entire variant `var_a` should be sorted in ascending order considering the column 2 that has dates

I know the way to do on the sheets but never worked on a variant , yes i can sort the sheet and then get the contents of the sheet into a `var_a` is one solution but sorting the sheet its taking 30 to 40 seconds which is undesired so i wanted to sort the variant instead of sheet.

Please help me with these Thanks

Comment: You must have a ton of rows if Excel is taking 30-40 seconds to sort the sheets. The sort features on the sheet are extreamlly fast and well implemented. :o

Comment: @Issun not the ton of rows I got just 20000 :) rows but instead every cell has a formula may be its just taking the time to refresh itself

Comment: Are you able to turn off Automatic Updating while you sort the sheets? That way the formulas don't have to evaluate and slow down the process.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Niko,

Rather than implement a sort routine inside the variant you should use Excel's native sorting for this. If you are struggling with your current file (I suggest you try sorting the current data with **Manual Calculation** first)  then a workaround would be to

- derive your variant from your current file
- dump the variant to a new workbook (closing your current file is an option)
- run the sort and then either create a new sorted variant array, or update the existing variant array
- dump the sorted variant array back to your original file (or manipulate further as needed)

Answer (score 0):

Here's a great place to pick up a vb6 sorting algorithm to fit your need: http://www.codeguru.com/vb/gen/vb_misc/algorithms/article.php/c14627

And just remember that you may need to wrap the variant variables in a conversion function (i.e. cint(), cstr(), etc.) if you want them to sort properly.  For example, you don't want to sort 1000 and 20 as strings because it will put 1000 first.